# Create column listing ascii control keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, ascii, charindex, control-characters

I need to create a table containing ascii control keys (code range between 0 and 31).

My first try:

```
CREATE TABLE control_characters(
    n int,
    [character] varchar(1)
);

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 0 AS n, CAST(0 AS varchar(1)) AS c

    UNION ALL

    SELECT n+1 AS n, CAST(n+1 AS varchar(1)) AS c
    FROM cte
    WHERE n<=30
)
INSERT INTO control_characters(n, [character])
SELECT n,c FROM cte;

SELECT * FROM control_characters;
```

[image]

```
SELECT CAST(cc.[character] AS int) AS pb, s.*
FROM file_extract_staging s
CROSS JOIN control_characters cc
WHERE CHARINDEX(cc.[character], s.absolute_path_unique) != 0
```

Comment: When you have a `varchar(1)` how are you expecting the  numbers 10 and over to fit in it? 10 has 2 characters, `'1'` and `'0'`. Or do you actually want `CHAR(n)`, not a `varchar` with the value of `n` (for example `'10'`)?

Comment: my ultimate goal is to detect control characters in a column containing file system absolute file paths

Comment: Can the first argument to CHARINDEX be an int ? I dont want to detect '3' in an absolute file system path, I want to detect the special character with ascii code 3.

Comment: *"Can the first argument to CHARINDEX be an int"* Yes, but it would be implicitly converted to a character expression. So `100` would be implicitly converted to `'100'`.

Comment: That's what I don't want

Comment: So what *do* you want...

Answer (score 1):

You should use the CHAR function for it.

Also, it's more efficient to use char(1) instead of varchar(1).

```
CREATE TABLE control_characters(
    n int,
    [character] char(1)
);
GO
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 0 AS n, CHAR(0) AS c

    UNION ALL

    SELECT n+1 AS n, CHAR(n+1) AS c
    FROM cte
    WHERE n<=30
)
INSERT INTO control_characters(n, [character])
SELECT n,c FROM cte;
GO
SELECT * FROM control_characters;
```

Comment: In effect, it seems to have produced a listing of control characters. Thanks a lot!

Comment: And the CHARINDEX function could use the CHAR as a first argument. Very good thank you!